# Anti-Realism about Higher-Order Vagueness

Tags: logic, realism

Who are the main anti-realists about higher-order vagueness? Would Crispin Wright be one? And, if so, is he a universal or partial anti-realist?

Answer (score 1):

Crispin Wright in fact denies higher-order vagueness. In that sense he's an anti-realist about that notion. See his recent paper 'The Illusion of Higher-Order Vagueness':

http://web.mit.edu/philosophy/colloquia/wright.pdf

But what does it mean to be a partial versus a universal anti-realist?

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Wright's position on Realism suggests a possible interpretation by quantifying over different discourses which we may or may not wish to ascribe a realist notion of truth-aptness, but we might ask "are we interested in universal anti-realism whether the property is truth-apt *in the same way* in all discourses, or simply *in some way*?"